# How to change the color of a treeinput icon?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I'm using the `treeInput` shinyWidget and the caret is black.  My site theme puts it against a dark gray background.  I can't figure out how to change the color to make it more visible.  I've been directed to keep a dark background, so I really need to change the color of the expander.  Here's what it looks like:

```
library(shiny);
library(shinydashboard);
library(shinydashboardPlus);
library(shinyWidgets);
library(fresh);

my_theme = create_theme(
  adminlte_color(
    light_blue = "#A7A7A7"
  )
)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  width="420",
  sidebarMenu(
    treeInput(
      inputId = "solutionPORFiltersCheckbox",
      label = "POR",
      choices = create_tree(
        data.frame(
          "All" = c("All"),
          "Years" = c(
            "0",
            paste0(as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-2),"-"),
            as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1),
            as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))),
            as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+1),
            as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+2),
            paste0(as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+3),"+")
          ),
          "Category" = c("UNCLASSIFIED", "PAST", "LAST_YEAR", "THIS_YEAR", "NEXT_YEAR","NEXT2_YEAR","FUTURE")
        ),
        levels = c("All","Years"),
        levels_id = c("All","Category")
      ),
      selected = c("All"),
      returnValue = "id",
      closeDepth = 0
    )
  )
)
body = dashboardBody(
  use_theme(my_theme),
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: expander_dark]

I've tried going into dev tools, but I can't seem to find a selector/style combo that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go using `CSS`:

```
.treejs .treejs-switcher::before, .treejs .treejs-switcher:hover::before {
     border-top: 4px solid white;
}
```

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(fresh)

my_theme = create_theme(
    adminlte_color(
        light_blue = "#A7A7A7"
    )
)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              .treejs .treejs-switcher::before,
                              .treejs .treejs-switcher:hover::before {
                                  border-top: 4px solid white;
                              }
                              '))),
    width="420",
    sidebarMenu(
        treeInput(
            inputId = "solutionPORFiltersCheckbox",
            label = "POR",
            choices = create_tree(
                data.frame(
                    "All" = c("All"),
                    "Years" = c(
                        "0",
                        paste0(as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-2),"-"),
                        as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1),
                        as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))),
                        as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+1),
                        as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+2),
                        paste0(as.character(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))+3),"+")
                    ),
                    "Category" = c("UNCLASSIFIED", "PAST", "LAST_YEAR", "THIS_YEAR", "NEXT_YEAR","NEXT2_YEAR","FUTURE")
                ),
                levels = c("All","Years"),
                levels_id = c("All","Category")
            ),
            selected = c("All"),
            returnValue = "id",
            closeDepth = 0
        )
    )
)
body = dashboardBody(
    use_theme(my_theme),
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar,
    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it like this:

1. Add an HTML ID to the tree element in your Shiny App, e.g. `#tree`
2. Use your browser's developer tools to find the caret element that the black color is defined on, e.g. the top-level `div` under `#tree`. Try to edit the color in the developer tools until it works.
3. Add inline-CSS to your Shiny App: https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/css/
4. Add CSS code for editing the caret, in the same way you did in the developer tools, for example:

   #tree > div {
   color: #fff;
   }